# Extract domain_name alone from email_id in Hive

Tags: sql, regex, hive, hiveql

In my Hive table, i have an email address column : xxxx@gmail.com 
i want to display "gmail" alone. I tried using regexp_extract but not getting the desired output. nowhere near.

Also for email ids like xxxx@ffff.nec.co.jp , i want the output to be "ffff.nec.co"

Below is my expression : select regexp_extract('xxxx@gmail.com','.([^.]+)')
but it does not bring the desired output. 
Please help me out guys. Regexp or substr is fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1

```
hive> select  regexp_extract('xxxx@gmail.com'       ,'@(.*)\\.',1);
OK
gmail

hive> select  regexp_extract('xxxx@ffff.nec.co.jp'  ,'@(.*)\\.',1);
OK
ffff.nec.co
```

Option 2

```
hive> select  regexp_extract('xxxx@gmail.com'       ,'(?<=@).*(?=\\.)',0);
OK
gmail

hive> select  regexp_extract('xxxx@ffff.nec.co.jp'  ,'(?<=@).*(?=\\.)',0);
OK
ffff.nec.co
```